# Swipe/drag between CSS objects

Tags: javascript, css, slider, hammer.js

I'm working on a responsive website, where I have a slider with "cards".
If I were to just animate between the three states, this was an easy job, but I can't wrap my head around how I can drag/swipe and calculate the position of the cards, by the mouse/finger `x position`.

I'm planning on using [Hammer JS](http://hammerjs.github.io/), and remember their initial demo, which was this type of slider that they controlled, but they replaced the old website.

How can I calculate the position of the three cards, based on the three states, and controlled by the mouse `x.position`? I can't figure out a way to do this...

I've made a JS Fiddle with pure CSS, with the three states: http://jsfiddle.net/2sqe8dve/

Thanks... :-)

[image: Illustration]

Comment: You may want to look into this, I used this before and it works amazingly. [iDangero Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php)

Comment: I like Hammer JS better, but thanks for the input.